# Keep a button within boundaries

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I'm still incredible new to android programming (like 3 weeks old) but I'm slowly getting the hang of things.  I've looked on different websites for an answer but I haven't found anything yet.

My Java code so far (at least what's relevant):

```
view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
backgroundImageName = String.valueOf(view.getTag());

view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int myNewX = (int)event.getX(); //this line and the next get the X & Y coordinates of wherever the mouse clicked
        int myNewY = (int)event.getY();
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_text);

        // find a way to keep the button within the borders of the white square
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) { //checks if the mouse click was released
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button.setX(myNewX - 160); //this line and the next set the coordinates of the button (plus the adjustment)
            button.setY(myNewY + 70); //to make the button by above and in the middle of where the mouse clicked
        }
        else
        {
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

and my XML code so far (at least what's relevant):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/white_background"
    android:tag="white"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_text"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="71dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />
```

What I'm trying to do is keep the button within the boundaries shown in the picture but I'm not sure how to do this.  I've got an idea of how it's supposed to work which is:

`If mouseclick (the event) is outside the border {
set the x coordinate of the button to the edge of the border
and the same for the y coordinate 
}`

I've been trying to get it to properly work but it simply refuses to.  If anyone can help me figure out the code I need to make it work, I would really appreciate the help.

Thank you

[image: borders]

Answer (score 1):

> First create a boundary check and then perform your task:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //obtain the boundaries of the view
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
    rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());

    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
       //Catches out of boundary user's movement.
       if(!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + 
        (int) event.getY())){

       button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       //perform your other calculations

    }

    return true;
}
```

});

> Note:  From API 14 you can use: Android MotionEvent's ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_HOVER_ENTER